# Text over Thumbnail

Tags: css, asp.net, vb.net

I need to put a price (text) over some thumbnails. I found the following code which works..

CSS

```
.col-md-4 {
    display: table;
}

.thumbnail{
    position:relative;
}

.thumbnail img{
    max-width:100%;
}

.thumbnail h1{
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:0;
  color:lightgrey;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
  transform:translateY(-50%); /* doesn't work in IE9 and older I'm affraid */
  margin:0;
}
```

ASP.NET

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Nail(thumb).jpg">
         <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

However, I want to try to and integrate the above to the following complicated code line and I haven't got a clue where to start (It was written for me). Here's the line..

```
Dim liByLiteral As New LiteralControl("<li><a href='http://images.example.com/" & filenameAndPrice(0) & "' class=""nyroModal"" rel=""gal" & DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "accountID").ToString & """ title=""" & filenameAndPrice(2) & " - PRICE: £" & filenameAndPrice(4) & """ onclick=""openImage('" & filenameAndPrice(1) & "', '" & txtItem.ClientID & "', '" & filenameAndPrice(0) & "');""><img class='lazy" & opacity & "' data-src='http://images.example.com/thumbnails/" & filenameAndPrice(0) & "' height='120' width='120' src='./files/images/loader.png' /></a></li>")
```

filenameAndPrice(4) is the price of the item. I'm happy with it being added to the Nyromodal Title but needs to be displayed over the thumbnail image as well. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: do you want to it from server?

Answer (score 0):

add runat server attribute and give Ids to your html controls.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img runat="server" id="tmdiv" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b9/Nail(thumb).jpg">
             <h1 runat="server" id="myheaderid" >Hello</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
```

On the server, now you can access these and can add any html attribute.
like ;

```
   myheaderid.InnerHtml= liByLiteral 
   tmdiv.atrributes.add("title", filenameAndPrice(4))
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. I'm just learning so apologies if I'm a bit lost. The Asp.Net code in my Question is just an example I found.. It's that long VB code line which I need to manipulate somehow.